# hibernate sorted map mapping? ERROR: HHH000091

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, sortedset

Hello all I'm new to Hibernate, and so I'm following some tutorials in the internet. But this example gives me the following error.

Any ideas ??

**update 1 -**
I tried to fix the bug so many times, but still couldn't do it.
When debugging I found that *`empID`* is NULL in `addEmployee` method.
I think that is the reason for this problem.

> Sep 24, 2015 4:20:54 PM
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterMethodImpl set ERROR:
>   HHH000123: IllegalArgumentException in class: Employee, setter method
>   of property: certificates Sep 24, 2015 4:20:54 PM
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterMethodImpl set ERROR:
>   HHH000091: Expected type: java.util.SortedMap, actual value:
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentMap
>   IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property
>   [Employee.certificates (expected type = java.util.SortedMap)]; target
>   = [Employee@3145028a], property value = [{BusinessManagement=Certificate@18bbd9e6,
>   ComputerScience=Certificate@54de97b9,
>   ProjectManagement=Certificate@61bb1e36}]  at
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterMethodImpl.set(SetterMethodImpl.java:99)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:607)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:220)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4510)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:261)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:109)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:678)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:670)    at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:665)     at
>   ManageEmployee.addEmployee(ManageEmployee.java:60)    at
>   ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:26)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterMethodImpl.set(SetterMethodImpl.java:44)
>     ... 21 more Sep 24, 2015 4:20:54 PM
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterMethodImpl set ERROR:
>   HHH000123: IllegalArgumentException in class: Employee, setter method
>   of property: certificates Sep 24, 2015 4:20:54 PM
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterMethodImpl set ERROR:
>   HHH000091: Expected type: java.util.SortedMap, actual value:
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentMap
>   IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property
>   [Employee.certificates (expected type = java.util.SortedMap)]; target
>   = [Employee@54b00534], property value = [{BusinessManagement=Certificate@3f7e6be2,
>   ComputerScience=Certificate@4dce2ff}]     at
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterMethodImpl.set(SetterMethodImpl.java:99)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:607)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:220)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4510)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:261)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:109)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:678)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:670)    at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:665)     at
>   ManageEmployee.addEmployee(ManageEmployee.java:60)    at
>   ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:34)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterMethodImpl.set(SetterMethodImpl.java:44)
>     ... 21 more Sep 24, 2015 4:20:54 PM
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator
>   initiateService INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to
>   load is required for loading  at
>   org.hibernate.event.spi.LoadEvent.(LoadEvent.java:92)   at
>   org.hibernate.event.spi.LoadEvent.(LoadEvent.java:62)   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2624)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:955)     at
>   ManageEmployee.updateEmployee(ManageEmployee.java:106)    at
>   ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:40)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

RDBMS tables

```
create table EMPLOYEE (
   id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
   first_name VARCHAR(20) default NULL,
   last_name  VARCHAR(20) default NULL,
   salary     INT  default NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create table CERTIFICATE (
   id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
   certificate_type VARCHAR(40) default NULL,
   certificate_name VARCHAR(30) default NULL,
   employee_id INT default NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

POJO Classes

```
import java.util.*;

public class Employee {
   private int id;
   private String firstName; 
   private String lastName;   
   private int salary;
   private SortedMap certificates;

   public Employee() {}
   public Employee(String fname, String lname, int salary) {
      this.firstName = fname;
      this.lastName = lname;
      this.salary = salary;
   }
   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }
   public void setId( int id ) {
      this.id = id;
   }
   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }
   public void setFirstName( String first_name ) {
      this.firstName = first_name;
   }
   public String getLastName() {
      return lastName;
   }
   public void setLastName( String last_name ) {
      this.lastName = last_name;
   }
   public int getSalary() {
      return salary;
   }
   public void setSalary( int salary ) {
      this.salary = salary;
   }

   public SortedMap getCertificates() {
      return certificates;
   }
   public void setCertificates( SortedMap certificates ) {
      this.certificates = certificates;
   }
}
```

Comparator

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class MyClass implements Comparator <String>{
   public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
      final int BEFORE = -1;
      final int AFTER = 1;

      /* To reverse the sorting order, multiple by -1 */
      if (o2 == null) {
         return BEFORE * -1;
      }

      Comparable thisCertificate = o1;
      Comparable thatCertificate = o2;

      if(thisCertificate == null) {
         return AFTER * 1;
      } else if(thatCertificate == null) {
         return BEFORE * -1;
      } else {
         return thisCertificate.compareTo(thatCertificate) * -1;
      }
   }
}
```

Certificate Class

```
public class Certificate implements Comparable <String>{
   private int id;
   private String name; 

   public Certificate() {}
   public Certificate(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }
   public void setId( int id ) {
      this.id = id;
   }
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
   public void setName( String name ) {
      this.name = name;
   }
   public int compareTo(String that){
      final int BEFORE = -1;
      final int AFTER = 1;

      if (that == null) {
         return BEFORE;
      }

      Comparable thisCertificate = this;
      Comparable thatCertificate = that;

      if(thisCertificate == null) {
         return AFTER;
      } else if(thatCertificate == null) {
         return BEFORE;
      } else {
         return thisCertificate.compareTo(thatCertificate);
      }
   }
}
```

Hibernate Mapping File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the employee detail. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <map name="certificates" cascade="all" sort="MyClass">
         <key column="employee_id"/>
         <index column="certificate_type" type="string"/>
         <one-to-many class="Certificate"/>
      </map>
      <property name="firstName" column="first_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="lastName" column="last_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="salary" column="salary" type="int"/>
   </class>

   <class name="Certificate" table="CERTIFICATE">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the certificate records. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <property name="name" column="certificate_name" type="string"/>
   </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Application Class

```
import java.util.*;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException; 
import org.hibernate.Session; 
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class ManageEmployee {
   private static SessionFactory factory; 
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try{
         factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
      }catch (Throwable ex) { 
         System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
         throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
      }
      ManageEmployee ME = new ManageEmployee();
      /* Let us have a set of certificates for the first employee  */
      TreeMap set1 = new TreeMap();
      set1.put("ComputerScience", new Certificate("MCA"));
      set1.put("BusinessManagement", new Certificate("MBA"));
      set1.put("ProjectManagement", new Certificate("PMP"));

      /* Add employee records in the database */
      Integer empID1 = ME.addEmployee("Manoj", "Kumar", 4000, set1);

      /* Another set of certificates for the second employee  */
      TreeMap set2 = new TreeMap();
      set2.put("ComputerScience", new Certificate("MCA"));
      set2.put("BusinessManagement", new Certificate("MBA"));

      /* Add another employee record in the database */
      Integer empID2 = ME.addEmployee("Dilip", "Kumar", 3000, set2);

      /* List down all the employees */
      ME.listEmployees();

      /* Update employee's salary records */
      ME.updateEmployee(empID1, 5000);

      /* Delete an employee from the database */
      ME.deleteEmployee(empID2);

      /* List down all the employees */
      ME.listEmployees();

   }

   /* Method to add an employee record in the database */
   public Integer addEmployee(String fname, String lname, 
                                      int salary, TreeMap cert){
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;
      Integer employeeID = null;
      try{
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         Employee employee = new Employee(fname, lname, salary);
         employee.setCertificates(cert);
         employeeID = (Integer) session.save(employee); 
         tx.commit();
      }catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }finally {
         session.close(); 
      }
      return employeeID;
   }

   /* Method to list all the employees detail */
   public void listEmployees( ){
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;
      try{
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         List employees = session.createQuery("FROM Employee").list(); 
         for (Iterator iterator1 = 
                           employees.iterator(); iterator1.hasNext();){
            Employee employee = (Employee) iterator1.next(); 
            System.out.print("First Name: " + employee.getFirstName()); 
            System.out.print("  Last Name: " + employee.getLastName()); 
            System.out.println("  Salary: " + employee.getSalary());
            SortedMap<String, Certificate> map = 
                                               employee.getCertificates();
            for(Map.Entry<String,Certificate> entry : map.entrySet()){
               System.out.print("\tCertificate Type: " +  entry.getKey());
               System.out.println(",  Name: " + 
                                        (entry.getValue()).getName());
            }
         }
         tx.commit();
      }catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }finally {
         session.close(); 
      }
   }
   /* Method to update salary for an employee */
   public void updateEmployee(Integer EmployeeID, int salary ){
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;
      try{
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         Employee employee = 
                    (Employee)session.get(Employee.class, EmployeeID); 
         employee.setSalary( salary );
         session.update(employee);
         tx.commit();
      }catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }finally {
         session.close(); 
      }
   }
   /* Method to delete an employee from the records */
   public void deleteEmployee(Integer EmployeeID){
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;
      try{
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         Employee employee = 
                   (Employee)session.get(Employee.class, EmployeeID); 
         session.delete(employee); 
         tx.commit();
      }catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }finally {
         session.close(); 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Just for testing, have you tried replacing the `SortedMap` with something like a 'simple' `HashMap`?

Comment: @DaDaDom Yes, I tried that way and got it correct. Actually I'm trying to practise different ways of mapping - and now I'm stuck in `SortedMap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem regarding Hibernate version. You should always make sure that you have taken the correct version of the package.

For this example it should be `Hibernate 3x`.